# Change values from dataframe if two columns are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm cleaning up a dataframe to train a machine learning model and I found that some entries have two different values in one column. For example:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | foo |
| 1234 | bar |

Since the value in column A is `1234` for both entries, the value in column B should be `foo` (or `bar`) in both cases.

I tried a brute force approach to this:

```
for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df.iterrows():
        if (row1['A'] == row2['A']) and ((row1['B'] != row2['B'])):
            print(f'Found duplicated A with different B!')
            row1['B'] == row2['B']
            row1['C'] == row2['C'] == False
```

But probably there is an easier way to do this that I can't see. Does pandas have any methods to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform('first')` (or `'last'`):

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first')
```

Comment: Thanks! It's so simple I'm ashamed i didn't see it hahaha. I'll mark as accepted.